# What's the opposite of telemetry?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

The word is derived from Greek the roots tele, "remote", and metron, "measure". So what word is opposite?

Comment: If telemetry is remote measuring, what do you consider the opposite? Local not-measuring?

Comment: Uh, "measurements"?  "Metrics"?

Comment: How can this be closed as unclear? The question seems perfectly clear, even if the answer is difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's an antonym. In the contexts where you would use "telemetry", any measurement that isn't specifically indicated to be remote would be assumed to be local, so you'd just say "measurement" or "metric".

For example, if an astronaut's spacesuit has a readout of their vital statistics, when the astronaut looks at it, it would be his metrics, but Mission Control would access it using telemetry.

Answer (score 1):

[Telemetry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/telemetry) is remote measurement.

It's opposite is **direct measurement**.

For example, in medicine a telemetry floor is where patients are placed on a remote cardiac monitor. They can wander freely around without wires. In a directly measured setting, they'd be wired to the cardiac monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a very pertinent question since [telemetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telemetry) is such a buzzword these days in the telecommunications industry.

I think the opposite has to indicate measurements are taken **locally** ... e.g. "local measurements" but it really depends what local vs remote means in your context .

I guess often it is whether done on same or different computer, but perhaps that is not always precise enough; should the delineation between the two be thread/process/container/virtual machine/host/cluster/etc.?

Maybe you would have to be  very specific e.g. *intra-host measurements*, etc. ?

I **think** that is better that vague terms like *non-remote measurements*, *local measurements* etc.